# When to many div become a nuisance?

Tags: html

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

the way I see it and would be tempted to do it is the following

[image]

but this is a lot of div and css

```
  <div class="route-information-container">
    <div class="route-information-container__header">
        <div class="route-information-container__name">DRONE ID ID </div>
        <div class="route-information-container__battery"><mat-icon svgIcon="battery-90"></mat-icon></div>
    </div>
    <div class="route-information-container__drone-info">
      <img  class="route-information-container__drone-logo" src="./assets/images/drones/drone_front.jpg" />
      <div class="route-information-container__drone-name">DroneID</div>
      <div class="route-information-container__drone-camera">CameraID</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

most of my HTML structure are always similar to this. I tend to put boxes everywhere, and I was wondering, is this a bad practice? what would be another way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the standard practice the structure is perfect.
You can also achieve the above structure using the below Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/m5dvx2q7/7/

```
 <div class="route-information-container__header">
  <div class="route-information-container__name">DRONE ID ID </div>
  <div class="route-information-container__battery">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="<battery-></battery->90">Right Section</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
<img  class="route-information-container__drone-logo" src="./assets/images/drones/drone_front.jpg" width="50px"/>
<div class= "bottom-section">
  <div class="route-information-container__drone-name">DroneID</div>
  <div class="route-information-container__drone-camera">CameraID</div>
</div>   


.route-information-container__header {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom-section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not incorrect and there will never be a problem.
But you can use **css selectors** to make clean structure in your html tags.
For example you can use this in your css file :

```
.route-information-container div:first-child {text-decoration: underline;}
.route-information-container div:last-child {color: red;}
```

Comment: Using CSS classes would be highly preferred over this as this relies on the HTML structure not changing.